Regex.findAll is getting stucked somewhere when nested json text is passed and never returning response
I'm trying to find all json patterns/patches in a string if there exists any. For that I'm using val regex = "\\{(?:[^{}]*|\\{[^{}]*\\})*\\}".toRegex(). It works fine for simple jsons or upto 2 step nested json. But if json is i.e of 3 steps nested then regex.findAll(row) never returns anything and doesn't even throw in exception or finally block if I place inside a try/catch. Sample method is as following that is causing the problem:
private fun testRegex() {
    lifecycleScope.launch(ioDispatcher) {
        try {
            val text =
                "{\"message\":\"Bad Gateway\",\"code\":502,\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Failed to get configuration of type: ae.network.transaction.domain.config.FeatureToggleResponse\",\"localizedMessage\":\"{error.processing.configFetchError}\",\"errorCode\":\"configFetchError\",\"domain\":\"processing\"}]}"
            val regex = "\\{(?:[^{}]*|\\{[^{}]*\\})*\\}".toRegex()
            val jsonMatches = regex.findAll(text)
            Log.d("json_matches", "jsonMatches= ${jsonMatches.count()}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("json_matches", "exception: Never comes here")
        } finally {
            Log.d("json_matches", "finally: Never comes here")
        }
    }
}

What I want is to atleast throw some exception so we can handle it someother way. But it seems to be going in an infinite process, because finally is also not reachable for such text. Any ideas would be appreciable.
Thanks

OK, whatever you are after, I think a regular unroll the loop will do: val regex = """\{[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*\}""".toRegex()

I've a text that may have other text along with some jsons inside that. I want to handle those jsons for some use case. For simplicity I've pasted only the straight json text. But it would be like "Hi! This is the sample 'abc','{"message":"Bad Gateway","code":502,"errors":[{"message":"Failed to get configuration of type: ae.network.transaction.domain.config.FeatureToggleResponse","localizedMessage":"{error.processing.configFetchError}","errorCode":"configFetchError","domain":"processing"}]}',"

You might still have to post-process the matches since they are JSON anyway.

after finding json matches, I want to replace those with some placeholder, do some processing on the text and replace those placeholders back or remove in some cases.

Thank you, your provided json seems to be working fine with so far provided samples. Can you please elaborate the difference in it.

See my answer here.

Note that you can also simply solve the problem using a possessive quantifier: \\{(?:[^{}]*|\\{[^{}]*\\})*+\\}. Obviously, the best in terms of performance is to combine the two advices: unrolled pattern + possessive quantifiers. If you want to match more than two levels, you can use a recursive pattern with the pypi/regex module: {[^{}]*+(?:(?0)[^{}]*)*+}

@CasimiretHippolyte It is Kotlin, not Python :) Yeah, possessive quantifiers will work, too.
